# Python mysql.connector and "DataError: 1406 (22001)" Trycatch

Tags: python, mysql

I use `mysql.connector` package for inserting data to my database. Unfortunately some of values might be longer then its estimated maximum length value in my db (`DataError: 1406 (22001)`). So I want to put in that place `None` value like in example below (on VARCHAR)

```
random_string = 'this is 25 character long'
max_len  = 24

if(len(random_string)>max_len ):
    print("mysql ERROR")#just for info not really neccesary
    random_string = None

print(random_string)#example result
```

As you can probalby imagine setting `max_len` for each field of multiple databases is quite problematic. How I can put (using `TryCatch` for example) `None` value when `n > max_len` and avoid the error?

Thank you in advance